# Conflict with Ember.js and URL fragment (#) with Ecwid

Tags: javascript, ember.js, pushstate

I'm using Ecwid with my Ember.js application, and I ran into a conflict. In short, Ecwid loads some JavaScript that embeds an e-commerce store into the page. The problem is that Ecwid and Ember both modify the URL fragment to keep track of state, since Ecwid is inherently its own single page application. Basically, I have two different JS libraries fighting over the URL.

So when I use an Ecwid component, the URL changes to an Ecwid URL, and Ember complains with `Assertion failed: The route !/~/category/id=2104219&offset=0&sort=normal was not found` because that is an Ecwid route, and not an Ember route.

I tried a catch-all Ember route, but that didn't really work because the Ember state changes away from the page I'm on.

Has anyone had to deal with a 2nd library that fights with Ember over the URL? If so, how did you maintain state and deal with the other application? As pushState and URL fragments become more and more popular, I could image this would become more and more relevant.

Comment: Really you're going to have to choose between the two, if they both are using the url for routing of some nature then they both rely on some notion of a base url, with a changing hash.  In Ember you can disable the location routing, but then you lose the routing capabilities of ember.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of :/ Well, in my case Ecwid is a hard requirement, so Ember has to go :*( For the sake of an answer, could you possibly post how to turn of Ember's routing capabilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really you're going to have to choose between the two, if they both are using the url for routing of some nature then they both rely on some notion of a base url, with a changing hash. In Ember you can disable the location routing, but then you lose the routing capabilities of ember.

To disable routing you'll just use the [NoneLocation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Location.html#toc_nonelocation)

> NONELOCATION
>
> Using NoneLocation causes Ember to not store the
>   applications URL state in the actual URL. This is generally used for
>   testing purposes, and is one of the changes made when calling
>   App.setupForTesting().

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'none'
});
```

I realize as I'm saying this, I'm partially lying, because you can use browser `history` instead of the hash.  So your urls would just change like so:

```
/emberHome/fooResource
/emberHome/fooResource/fooBar
```

instead of

```
/emberHome/#/fooResource
/emberHome/#/fooResource/fooBar
```

Unfortunately there are some major drawbacks to this, firstly your server needs to know to serve your ember app at /emberHome and essentially ignore all nested locations.  Secondly the browser support is fairly new (http://caniuse.com/history).  Thirdly, the support for recognizing the Ecwid won't be supported, and will likely be blasted away when transitioning to different routes.

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});
```

You can read more about it at http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Location.html#toc_historylocation

Answer (score 0):

Per the guides, you can tell Ember to not use the URL to interact with your application.

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/

Straight from the docs there -

> Finally, if you don't want the browser's URL to interact with your
>   application at all, you can disable the location API entirely. This is
>   useful for testing, or when you need to manage state with your Router,
>   but temporarily don't want it to muck with the URL (for example when
>   you embed your application in a larger page).

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'none'
});
```